# Are vacuum expectation values coordinate transform independent?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, coordinate-systems, vacuum, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

The energy radiated by some free, real-valued, scalar massless field $\phi$ in flat $1 + 1$ time and space dimensions is the vacuum expectation value of the $\{$00$\}$ entry of energy-momentum tensor.

Introduce:
$$\phi = \int d\omega \ (a^{\dagger}_{\omega} \phi_{\omega} + a_{\omega} \phi^{*}_{\omega})$$

where:

$$\phi_{\omega} = i  \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi \omega}} \left(e^{-i \omega v} - e^{-i \omega p(u)}\right)\ , \ \text{and}\ u, \ v$$

are the standard null co-ordinates.

Calculating the vacuum expectation value of the energy density:

$$\langle 0|T_{tt}|0\rangle, \ \ T_{tt} = \left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\right)^2$$

is straightforward, as only certain combinations of the annihilation and creation operators return a non $0$ answer when operating on the vacuum, and the final result is:

$$\langle 0|T_{tt}|0\rangle = \int \frac{\omega}{4 \pi} d\omega \ \left(1 + p^{\prime}(u)^2\right) \ .$$

However, one can make a tensor transform to the null-coordinates and work directly, where:

$$T_{tt} \to \left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u}\right)^2 \ .$$

When doing the calculation with this operator, I calculate the vacuum expectation value to be:

$$\int \frac{\omega}{4 \pi} d\omega \ \left(p^{\prime}(u)^2\right) \ .$$

This concerns me as I expected them to be equal, as no physical transformation has taken place.

Is my understanding flawed or is there a simple miscalculation?

Thank you

Comment: To answer the title, an example of a vacuum expectation value that does depend on the referential is the VEV of the number operator, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unruh_effect (or alternatively the article on Hawking Radiations)

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux The problem I had was that equality was broken before any intersting  non-inertial structure was introduced. Besides, as vacuum is usually taken to be in the asymptotically Minkowski space, and so the unruh effect would be $\langle \Phi | T_{tt} | \Phi \rangle$, $\Phi$ being a grand canonical ensemble of pure $\phi$ states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$T_{00}$ can be expressed in different representations, $T_{uu}$ is the energy density with the density being an infinitesimal $du$, and $T_{tt}$ is the energy density with density being an infinitesimal $dx$. Hence, they describe different quantities but recover the same value of energy when the integration boundaries describe the same space.